# R: can range(data.frame) exclude infinite values?

Tags: r, range, infinity

I am trying to find the [`range`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/range.html) of a data frame with infinite values:

```
> f <- data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(3,Inf))
> range(f)
[1]   1 Inf
> range(f,finite=TRUE)
Error in FUN(X[[2L]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
Calls: Summary.data.frame -> lapply -> FUN
> range(f$y)
[1]   3 Inf
> range(f$y,finite=TRUE)
[1] 3 3
```

Why am I getting the error?

Can I do better than

```
> do.call(range,lapply(f,range,finite=TRUE))
[1] 1 3
```

Is this a bug? Is it known? Should I report it?

Comment: `range(unlist(f),finite=TRUE)`?

Comment: is this a (known?) bug?

Comment: Hmm.. it looks like some methods issue. `range.default` works perfectly fine, for example `range.default(f, finite = TRUE)`

Comment: Here's the source code for [`do_range`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/summary.c#L783-L804)

Comment: @DavidArenburg: so, this is a bug. Are you going to fix it? thanks!

Comment: Me going to fix it? I'm not sure what you mean (I'm not part of the R-Core team) but we could try to [fill a bug](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/)

Comment: @DavidArenburg: sorry, I assumed you were; will you file a bug or should I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use (as David points out in comments):

```
range.default(f, finite=TRUE)
# [1] 1 3
```

or

```
range(f, finite=1)
# [1] 1 3
```

The function is erroneously requiring `finite` to be numeric, but then properly uses it in removing infinite values.  Notice:

```
f2 <- data.frame(x=1:2, y=3:4)
range(f2, finite=TRUE)  # Error
```

Clearly something funny is happening with the generic being a primitive and your argument being an object, likely related to (from `?range`):

> range is a generic function: methods can be defined for it directly or via the Summary group generic. For this to work properly, **the arguments ... should be unnamed**, and dispatch is on the first argument.

So basically, when checking its arguments, it thinks `finite=TRUE` is part of the data to check the range on, and since it is a logical it fails the test for numericness.  That said, once it gets past that check it computes properly.

To confirm:

```
range(f, finite=2000)
# [1] 1 3
```

Answer (score 2):

There are probably multiple possibilities.  If everything is numeric then one is

```
> f <- data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(3,Inf))
> range(as.matrix(f),finite=TRUE)
[1] 1 3
```